# Python Convert list of tuple in to string containing different types of format

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want  to convert below list of tuple into single string, where output string should replace datetime obj into string datetime format None should be replace with 'None' and integer should be replace with str(int)

```
rows = [('name', 25,  datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 9, 0, 0, 1), None), ('name2', 26,  datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 9, 0, 0, 1), None)]
```

I want below out put as string

```
'(('name', '25',  '2018-01-09 00:00:01', 'None'), ('name2', '26',  2018-01-09 00:00:01, 'None')]'
```

expectation :

'((str, str, str, str), (str, str, str, str))'

I tried following

```
print('(%s)' % ','.join(str(i) for i in rows  ))
```

but it is not converting in proper format. I am missing something

Comment: "below output" is not a valid string.

Comment: Do you want to convert tuple?

Comment: Your expected output tells that all you need to do is `print(str(rows))`

Comment: What output are you getting instead?

Comment: I have updated my question, Please have a look again

Comment: Your example output is still not a valid string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import datetime
rows = [('name', 25,  datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 9, 0, 0, 1), None), ('name2', 26,  datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 9, 0, 0, 1), None)]
print(str(tuple(tuple(map(str, item)) for item in rows)))
```

or if your prefer list comprehension instead of `map()`

```
print(str(tuple(tuple(str(ele) for ele in item) for item in rows)))
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code is converting each tuple within the list to `str`, rather than *each item within the tuples*.

This line will convert each item in the tuple to str, using tuples and generator expressions:

```py
>>> str(tuple(tuple(str(x) for x in r) for r in rows))
"(('name', '25', '2018-01-09 00:00:01', 'None'), ('name2', '26', '2018-01-09 00:00:01', 'None'))"
```

Note that there are *two* `for` keywords, to traverse both levels of your structure.